# Can people in heaven and hell ordinarily communicate with one another?

Tags: jannah, jahannam

In these ayat, the companions of the Fire and the companions of Paradise talk to one another.

> And the companions of Paradise will call out to the companions of the Fire, "We have already found what our Lord promised us to be true. Have you found what your Lord promised to be true?" They will say, "Yes." Then an announcer will announce among them, "The curse of Allah shall be upon the wrongdoers." -- [Qur'an 7:44](https://quran.com/7/44)
>
> And the companions of the Fire will call to the companions of Paradise, "Pour upon us some water or from whatever Allah has provided you." They will say, "Indeed, Allah has forbidden them both to the disbelievers." -- [Qur'an 7:50](https://quran.com/7/50)
>
> [Who will be] in gardens, questioning each other About the criminals, [And asking them], "What put you into Saqar?" They will say, "We were not of those who prayed, Nor did we used to feed the poor. And we used to enter into vain discourse with those who engaged [in it], And we used to deny the Day of Recompense Until there came to us the certainty." -- [Qur'an 74:40-47](https://quran.com/74/40-47)

(See the section *Conversations between the people of Paradise and the people of Hell* at [IslamReligion.com](https://www.islamreligion.com/articles/5257/viewall/conversations-in-paradise-and-hell/).)

This raises the question:

**Question**: Can people in heaven and hell ordinarily communicate with one another?

If people in heaven and hell can ordinarily communicate with one another, it raises some bizarre problems, e.g., imagine talking to a close relative who is in hell; difficulties communicating while being [punished without respite](https://quran.com/2/162).

So perhaps these ayat are meant to be a metaphorical *I told you so*.  And if they're taken literally, it may still just mean this is a once-off case.

I don't know which it is though.

Comment: 1. In a large company, the E-level (executive) are working in floor +50 and other normal people are working below them. Normals guys don't have elevator access to +50. Yet E-levels can visit everyone and every floor. AFAIK it's almost the same Heaven and Hell. How it's managed? I don't know. 2. I think inherent in your question is that for two people to communicate they need to be at the same place...but I don't think that's the same case for afterlife. We have Skype, video Projectors. Perhaps they have some more advanced technology that would allow remote communication :D

Comment: Razi mentions some points [here](http://altafasir.com/al-quran/surat/7/al-araf/44/razi) (in arabic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a brief answer based on my research (as some related points):

Firstly, in the Quran, it is utilized “Nadi/نادی”, which commonly is used for speaking/speech from far distance.

**Secondly, as e.g. you can see there can be very far communication by diverse electronic devices, then perhaps there will such relation there in that situation, and actually it doesn’t mean that their communication is in the same place (which is so good for both sides…). Or, for instance, it can be like the speaking of a prisoner (in a prison, by phone, behind the glass as a bad arrested place) with the free person who is outside the glass and is talking …**

Thirdly, seemingly, the Holy Qur'an has not mentioned a very explicit info. concerning that.

Fourthly, their communication doesn’t seem to be a long/permanently relation.

**Fifthly, and actually finally, I assume such (at least limited communication) even can be a sort of punishment for the persons who are in the hell too, why? Because when they see the folks who are in paradise (e.g. their family or friend and so on), then they’ll get very more sad/furious for missing such great opportunity for going to such fantastic place (heaven) instead of hell, and it can be an awful spiritual punishment for them (as well as probably in being in the fire …)**

---

Source:

[www.askdin.com](http://www.askdin.com/showthread.php?t=17797) + my assumption.

---

Hopefully it helps you.